# Sort table columns' (tr) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, sorting, html-table

I got this table and I need to sort columns by an attribute (`kind_id`) but not simply ascendant or descendant, I got an array of ids that the sorting should follow.

This is an example of column:

```
<tr id='music' class='unchecked' selezionato='no'  kind_id='203'>
    <td id='music' width='179px'>
       <div id='nome_music'>
           Rock
       </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is an example of the array

```
["203", "10", "12", "15", "25", "46", "56", "61", "102", "104", "114", "116", "121", "138", "142", "145", "187", "189", "190", "204", "205", "208", "214", "220"]
```

How could I do this?

Comment: is it completely static, or will the content change

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library like underscore.js and utilize the built in method `sortBy`.

[underscore.js sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sort function. Assuming your table element has an id ("myTable") and that your array variable is called `arrayOfIndices`:

```
function sortById (row1, row2){
    return arrayOfIndices.indexOf($(row1).attr("kind_id")) > arrayOfIndices.indexOf($(row2).attr("kind_id")) ? 1 : -1; 
}

$("#myTable tr").sort(sortById).appendTo("#myTable");
```